# Histidine-Boc deprotectection

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, chemical-biology, proteins, amino-acids

A question on Fmoc-solid phase peptide synthesis (SPPS). Is Boc-protected Histidine too labile? Merck's [website](https://www.merckmillipore.com/JP/ja/product/Fmoc-HisBoc-OH.CHA,MDA_CHEM-852052?ReferrerURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) shows  Boc is labile to treatment with Piperidine. Anyone with such experience?

Comment: Comments here support this https://www.researchgate.net/post/Did-anyone-observe-spontaneous-Boc-removal-from-histidine  as does a mention here http://cem.com/media/contenttype/media/literature/ap0170v1-CEM.pdf

Comment: Also see this paper  Sieber, P.; Riniker, B. Tetrehedron Lett. 1987, 28, 6031 –6034